# Reduce works for simple inequalities in Reals but not in Integers

Tags: simplifying-expressions, inequalities, logic

In the domain of `Reals` `Reduce` correctly reduces the system to `True`:

```
Reduce[a > b || a <= c || b > c, {a, b, c}, Reals]
```

But it fails in the case of `Integers`:

```
Reduce[a > b || a <= c || b > c, {a, b, c}, Integers] // FullSimplify
(******)
(* (C[1] | C[2] | C[3] | C[4]) \[Element] Integers && C[1] >= 0 && 
 C[2] >= 0 && C[3] >= 0 && 
 C[4] >= 
  0 && ((a + C[3] == C[1] + C[2] && 
     1 + b + C[3] + C[4] == C[2]) || (a + C[3] == 1 + C[1] + C[2] && 
     b + C[3] + C[4] == C[2]) || (b + C[3] == C[1] + C[2] && 
     1 + c + C[3] + C[4] == C[2]) || (b + C[3] == 1 + C[1] + C[2] && 
     c + C[3] + C[4] == C[2]) || (c + C[3] == C[1] + C[4] && 
     a + C[2] + C[3] == C[1]))
*)
```

Interesting enough it works with the negation of original system:

```
Reduce[! (a > b || a <= c || b > c), {a, b, c}, Integers] (* False *)
```

What is the reason for this behavior and is it possible to `Reduce` to `True` in case of `Integers`?

UPD: Reduce works in case of adding universal quantification for:

```
Reduce[ForAll[{a, b, c}, (a > b || a <= c || b > c)], Integers] (*True*)
```

**UPD**:
The behavior seems a bit chaotic to me, probably I dont understand something basis.

More interesting examples:

```
Reduce[ForAll[{a, b, 
   c}, (a > b || a <= c || b > c)], Integers] (*True*)
```

```
Reduce[ForAll[{a, b, c}, (a > b || a <= c || b > c)], {a, b, 
  c}, Integers] (* ????? a\[Element]\[DoubleStruckCapitalZ]&&b\[Element]\
\[DoubleStruckCapitalZ]&&c\[Element]\[DoubleStruckCapitalZ]*)
```

```
Reduce[ForAll[{a, b, c}, {a, b, c} \[Element] 
   Integers, (a > b || a <= c || b > c)], {a, b, c}]  (*True*)
```

Comment: `Reduce[ForAll[{a, b, c}, (a > b || a <= c || b > c)], Integers]` is not equivalent to `Reduce[a > b || a <= c || b > c, {a, b, c}, Integers]`.

Comment: I believe so but what is the difference with `Reals` case?